# JavaFX8 Background Thread still interferes with GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, concurrency, javafx-8, antlr4

I want to write a JavaFX GUI that loads and parses a bigger file (22M) which takes about 30 seconds. However, when I start the parsing in a Task, the rest of the GUI is pretty unresponsive. It is however, not fully unresponsive, but still it hangs for several seconds now and then. To demonstrate that, I wrote a small application that shows the progress of the parsing in a progress bar and executes another task in parallel which simply updates a label every second. Now, this second task shouldn't be blocked by the first one, so I'm probably doing it wrong. Here's the code:

Task to tick every second:

```
class TimeTask extends Task<Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {
        while (true) {
            updateMessage(Instant.now().toString());
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Replacement for parsing the logfile:
The update method is called in 100ms steps from the parser.

```
public class ParseLogfileTask extends Task<Void> {

private LinkedList<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<Integer>();
private Random random = new Random();

@Override
protected Void call() {
    Instant startInstant = Instant.now();
    while (Duration.between(startInstant, Instant.now()).getSeconds() < 25) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            numbers.add((Integer) random.nextInt());
        }
        Collections.shuffle(numbers);
        Collections.sort(numbers);
        numbers.clear();
        updateParseProgress(
                (int) Duration.between(startInstant, Instant.now())
                        .toMillis(), 25000);
    }
    return null;
}

public void updateParseProgress(int currentIndex, int maxIndex) {
    updateProgress(currentIndex, maxIndex);
}
```

}

start method of the application:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar();
        Label label = new Label("new");
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(bar, label);
        root.getChildren().add(vbox);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Task<Void> timeTask = new TimeTask();
        Task<Void> logFileTask = new ParseLogfileTask();
        bar.progressProperty().bind(logFileTask.progressProperty());
        label.textProperty().bind(timeTask.messageProperty());
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            new Thread(timeTask).start();
            new Thread(logFileTask).start();
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** I removed a 5 seconds sleep after the start of the timeTask. It is not necessary for the real problem. The real problem is that the timeTask does not update the label every second as long as the logfileTask is running. Is merely updates every 1-5 seconds. As soon as the logfileTask is done, the timeTask updates the label exactly as it should. Could this have to do with Thread priorities? The logfileTask produces quite heavy load...

**EDIT 2:** I cannot reproduce the problem by using other ways to create load. I have those problems only with the parser, which was created by ANTLR and creates a huge parse-tree (many objects). However, since the parser is launched in a background thread, how could it interfere with the JavaFX Application thread?

**EDIT 3:** Looks like it is indeed the garbage collection. I replaced the logfile parsing with generating a huge list of numbers, sorting them and throwing them away again, and I could see the same gaps as with the parser running (not so often, but with larger impact)

Comment: How big is the parse-tree? I suppose if you are creating too many objects you may be forcing the garbage collector to run frequently, which could potentially block all running threads.

Comment: well, that could indeed be the case. The tree has about 7 mio tokens = leaf nodes.

Comment: I think that makes it an ANTLR question, more than a JavaFX question: so I will defer to people who know that technology (I don't). For some very general advice: try increasing the heap size for your JVM to see if that fixes the issue. If it can run with a heap size comfortably in the range you can expect your users to be able to use, then I'd just go with that option. If not, you'll probably need to find a different parse strategy. (I have no idea what you're parsing, obviously, but you might want to think along the lines of "event driven" parsing rather than "document model" parsing.)

Comment: I already thought about the idea to get rid of the parse-tree at all. In ANTLR the nice thing about parse trees is that they allow you to write a pure grammar (without java commands in it). As a sidenote: the document that I'm parsing is a [Robocup 2D simulation](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sserver/) [logfile](http://fei.edu.br/rcs/2D/2014/finals/final/match_1/201407241009-WrightEagle_3-vs-Gliders2014_2.rcg.gz) of a game. The goal is to build a JavaFX Monitor for those games.

Comment: @James_D if you would make the garbage collection suggestion an official answer, I would mark it solved for you. Don't want to take the credit myself

Answer (score 1):

The amout of operations you call in the **ParseLogfileTask** are way to many. It is like a while(true).
Use a Thread.sleep before the return null.

```
@Override
protected Void call() {
    Instant startInstant = Instant.now();
    while (Duration.between(startInstant, Instant.now()).getSeconds() < 25) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            numbers.add((Integer) random.nextInt());
        }
        Collections.shuffle(numbers);
        Collections.sort(numbers);
        numbers.clear();
        updateParseProgress(
                (int) Duration.between(startInstant, Instant.now())
                .toMillis(), 25000);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

So it worked for me.

Additionally it would be better to use

`ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
service.execute(timeTask);
service.execute(logFileTask);`

for calling your Threads.